# SimpleXML - Grab values into a single array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am using the following code to fetch the results from an XML feed online...

```
<?php
$url="http://www.domain.com/xmlapi-im/years.asp";
$xmlinfo = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($xmlinfo);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The results are like so...

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["table"]=>
  array(52) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2014"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2013"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2012"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2011"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2010"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2009"
    }
    [6]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2008"
    }
    [7]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2007"
    }
    [8]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2006"
    }
    [9]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2005"
    }
    [10]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2004"
    }
    [11]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2003"
    }
    [12]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2002"
    }
    [13]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2001"
    }
    [14]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2000"
    }
    [15]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1999"
    }
    [16]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1998"
    }
    [17]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1997"
    }
    [18]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1996"
    }
    [19]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#21 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1995"
    }
    [20]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1994"
    }
    [21]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#23 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1993"
    }
    [22]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#24 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1992"
    }
    [23]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1991"
    }
    [24]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1990"
    }
    [25]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#27 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1989"
    }
    [26]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#28 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1988"
    }
    [27]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#29 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1987"
    }
    [28]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#30 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1986"
    }
    [29]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#31 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1985"
    }
    [30]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#32 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1984"
    }
    [31]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#33 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1983"
    }
    [32]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#34 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1982"
    }
    [33]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#35 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1981"
    }
    [34]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#36 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1980"
    }
    [35]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#37 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1979"
    }
    [36]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#38 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1978"
    }
    [37]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#39 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1977"
    }
    [38]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#40 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1976"
    }
    [39]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#41 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1975"
    }
    [40]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#42 (1) {

      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1974"
    }
    [41]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#43 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1973"
    }
    [42]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#44 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1972"
    }
    [43]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1971"
    }
    [44]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1970"
    }
    [45]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1969"
    }
    [46]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#48 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1968"
    }
    [47]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#49 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1967"
    }
    [48]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#50 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1966"
    }
    [49]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#51 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1965"
    }
    [50]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#52 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1964"
    }
    [51]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#53 (1) {
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "1955"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to grab the values from "year" and put it into a single array, which I'll use later in a foreach loop. I'm not sure how to grab the values from this far down and I'm a bit stumped.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If all you need is the values for year, just use an xpath:http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Returns an array of SimpleXML objects that you can use from there.

Comment: Hey there. In this particular example, that is all I need. Though in a few moments, I'll need additional values as soon as I query the makes that go with the years.

Comment: Ok, so you want to be able to correlate the two? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Hey there. What I'd like to do is to get the value for year, but I also have other XML feeds I'm parsing that have more than one value that I have to obtain.

Comment: Can you post examples of those other feeds, and maybe what you've tried so far? I'd like to be able to help you.

Comment: Hey there. Of course -- thank you! So we want to start by grabbing the years available from here -- http://www.sizeitup.com/xmlapi-im/years.asp. Once we've done so, I'm trying to setup a foreach loop that would grab the makes that match each year from the feed. See the example feed for that here -- http://www.sizeitup.com/xmlapi-im/makes.asp?txtYear=2012

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43142/discussion-between-brian-schroeter-and-zarazthuztra)